# Forwarding ArangoDB (in docker) with traefik

Tags: arangodb, traefik

I am running an ArangoDB cluster (3 agents, 1 coordinator, and 1 DB) in Docker, but when I try to expose the GUI I get a partially rendered GUI.

From my understanding of the Traefik documentation, I need to add 2 sections.  Is it correct to forward the coordinator port?

Under http:

```
arango-coordinator:
  entrypoints:
    - "https"
  rule: "PathPrefix(`/_/arangodb`)"
  service: arangodb-coordinator
  tls: {}
```

Under services:

```
arangodb:
  loadBalancer:
    servers:
      - url: "http://arango-coordinator:7001"
```

[Example of a partially rendered image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZU6oj.png)